# There is a out of box way to convert a SimplifiedJson to a ExtendedJson?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-kafka-connector

I've a MongoDB Kafka Connector v1.3 configured with `output.json.formatter=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.json.formatter.SimplifiedJson`, so my UUID field is outputed like that: `"_id":"MSRJCs07SFy4sMpopdRvEA=="`.

But, one of clients of that Kafka message need to convert that SimplifiedJson in a valid ExtendedJson, and from that ExtendedJson instantiate a org.bson.BsonDocument (mongodb Java SDK), so the _id should be recongnized as a BsonBinary (UUID) with value 3124490a-cd3b-485c-b8b0-ca68a5d46f10.

Trying BsonDocument.parse directly from SimplifiedJson, that value `"_id":"MSRJCs07SFy4sMpopdRvEA=="` is treated as a BsonString.

The client can't do that manually because there is not standard in that field, may be a object id, a uuid or any other thing which make sense to the application that generate that data.

So, there is any built-in way in MongoDB library to convert a SimplifiedJson to a Bson with the same original field types (object id, binary, dates, numbers, etc)?

Comment: BSON is a binary format and is most likely not what you want. Perhaps you mean extended JSON to language native type conversion.

Comment: This, I will make the question clearer.

Comment: There is an ExtendedJson formatter next to the simplified one.

Comment: I can't simply switch to ExtendedJson in my Kafka Connect configuration because other clients exists and use SimplifiedJson. The main question is whether there is a way to "convert" a SimplifiedJson to a ExtendedJson.

Comment: The source code for Kafka connector is public, therefore I imagine you can write such a converter.